# When I press the button inside cardview, both cardview item and button is clicked

Tags: android, android-cardview

I have a Cardview with Button

card view layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="0.01dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="123dp"
        android:background="@drawable/posts_card_bg"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/post_title"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:alpha="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:text="title"
                android:textSize="30sp"/>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/post_body"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:text="Body"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/expand"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:background="@drawable/expand"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/post_id"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:text="99"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"

            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

PostCardAdapter.java

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ContactViewHolder holder, int position) {
   ......
    holder.btn_expand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //for showing details of item on dialog
            listener.onItemClicked(view);
        }
    });

}
```

Recyclerview item click

```
  listener = this;
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.cardlist_posts);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new PostCardAdapter(listener,db.getAllPosts(), R.layout.cardview_post));


    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int id) {
                    // TODO Handle item click
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShowPostDetails.class);
                    intent.putExtra("KEY_POST_ID", String.valueOf(id + 1));
                    System.out.println(String.valueOf(id + 1));
                    //Starting another activity to show post details
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            })
    );
```

MainActivity.java

```
  @Override
public void onItemClicked(View v) {
    DialogPostFragment df= new DialogPostFragment();
    df.show(getFragmentManager(), "Dialog");
}
```

When the button is pressed then the cardview item is clicked and ongoing back dialog is also opened.
I want to open  dialog only when I press the button.
Thank You.

Comment: please post the code that handle cardview item clicked

Comment: @PhanVanLinh  plz check

Comment: so you want different click listener for your cardview and button click?

Comment: @HourGlass yes I guess

Comment: you have added on Item touch listener right disable it , your button_expand will only get fired. if you want to have two click listener one for card and one for item. create two click listener class in your Activity and pass it to adapter assgin the click listener inside oncreateViewholder , view.clicklistener(yourlistener) for card and button_expand.clicklistener(youtlistenerfor button)

Answer (score 0):

I had faced exactly the same issue once.This is how I solved it :

add **id** to the first linear layout inside the cardview :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rowLL"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="123dp"
        android:background="@drawable/posts_card_bg"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        >
```

Now,in your **PostCardAdapter.java** :

```
public class PostCardAdapter extends RecyclerView
        .Adapter<ContactViewHolder> {

   ...

   private static MyClickListener myClickListener;

   ...

   public void setOnItemClickListener(MyClickListener myClickListener) {
       PostCardAdapter.myClickListener = myClickListener;
    }

   ...        

    public interface MyClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(int position, View v);
    }
}
```

Then,in your **ContactViewHolder**.java

```
public class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        private PostCardAdapter.MyClickListener myClickListener;

        ...

        public ContactViewHolder(final Context context, View itemView, PostCardAdapter.MyClickListener clickListener) {
           super(itemView);
            ...
            myClickListener = clickListener;
            itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowLL).setOnClickListener(this);
        }

       @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myClickListener.onItemClick(getLayoutPosition(), v);
        }
}
```